# Edit META in full page

Tags: html

I have a problem. In CKeditor fullpage source  the metatag  keywords description etc. do not have break line.

```
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="it"/>
<meta name="keywords" content="keyword1, keyword2.... "/>
<meta name="description" content=" Descrizione tua attività" >
<meta name="author" content="">​
```

Comment: Try posting code of what you've tried so far, and a better explanation of your problem. It's hard to understand exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why do you need a line break?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my post is not very clear. I put example:

```
File = 
<meta name="keywords" content="keyword1, keyword2.... "> 
<meta name="description" content=" Descrizione tua attività" > 
<meta name="author" content="">

File in source ckeditor 
<meta name="keywords" content="keyword1, keyword2.... "><meta name="description" content=" Descrizione tua attività" ><meta name="author" content="">
```

I do not know if it is displayed correctly. However all the three lines attached and not in command line